# How I can copy the text from a TextBox in a textFile?

Tags: c#, .net, text-files

I created a windows form application and I have a `TextBox` which has text as a file location like this : `C:\DATA\FOLDER`.

Also I have a text file in `d:\data\test.txt`which contains many lines but one defined line for `Location=""` .

How I can copy the location specified in the `TextBox` in the text file `test.txt` in the `Location=""` row, without mentioning the line number ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in one line

```
var path = @"d:\data\test.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(line => line.StartsWith("Location=\"")
        ? string.Format("Location=\"{0}\"", textBox1.Text)
        : line));
```

First you read all lines in file and if any of them starts with "Location="" then it will be replaced by the location in text box. At the end you write the result back to the file.

If you don't like to do it in one line (and for me not getting downvoted for it) then you can just split it

```
var path = @"d:\data\test.txt";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

var modifiedLines = lines.Select(line =>
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Location=\""))
    {
        return string.Format("Location=\"{0}\"", textBox1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        return line;
    }
});

File.WriteAllLines(path, modifiedLines);
```

I think sometimes writing more code reduces readability!

Comment: And the benefit of doing it in one line is...?

Comment: and I changed that with this : ? string.Format("Location=\"{0}\"", textBox1.Text

Comment: I have an additional question. I can define somewhere a variable for the address d:\data\test.txt, and when I want to use this just to call ? like a global var or something like this ?

Comment: yes. I've edited the answer to meet your requirements. @user

Comment: I think the only benefit is that I need to get 1 more upvote to reach daily cap today! @jeroenh

Comment: and it I can define in main to be available for all forms ?

Comment: you can put it like this in `Program` class: `public const string Path = @"d:\data\test.txt";` and access it anywhere in application by `Program.Path`

Comment: I don't to be so insistent but, if I want to conversely the process, to get the text from TextBox, and put in the "Location " from text file, how I can do this ?

Comment: I can't understand you. Please ask a new question and explain the problem there.

Comment: i made another question

Comment: You duplicated this question with exactly the same question. "User" wants to get a line in a config file, display it in the UI for editing, and then the edited version saved back to the file. Smells like homework....

Answer (score 4):

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
string filepath=textBox1.Text;
text = text.Replace("Location="" "," Location= "+filepath+");
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);
```

Comment: and if in location I have already a string like this Location="C:\temp" and I want to change with the data from TextBobx ?

Comment: This won't compile. You need to escape the double quotes at the Replace statement.

Comment: I have a lot of errors on this line text = text.Replace("Location="" "," Location= "D:\user\test.txt");

Answer (score 2):

This works too:

```
IList<string> output = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("d:\\data\\test.txt"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith("Location=\""))
        {
            line = String.Format("Location=\"{0}\"", "TextBox.Text");
        }

        output.Add(line);
    }
}

File.WriteAllText("d:\\data\\test.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output));
```